# DNS problem likely caused by fortinet VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, dns

I have two Mac computers which have the same problem: I had Fortinet VPN installed which routes the company's domain when typed to an internal server.

It looks like this has changed a setting on both my computers.
So, I cannot enter this web address as it stops me on all browsers.
Fortinet has been manually removed but I cannot find where the setting would be to resolve.

Comment: More than likely your DNS settings have changed.  Can you run the following command and post the output with an [edit]?  `ipconfig getpacket en0 | awk -F "{|}" '/domain_name_server/ {print $2}'`. I'm assuming you're using WiFi on a MacBook.  If it's something different, try `en1` instead.  If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I suppose you’ve already tried a restart of macOS. Next thing you could do is to reset the network settings.

Comment: I have wiped one of the Macs and rebuilt everything & now have access via Wordpress & VS code. All work ok. The second I have tried your code and got the return Alexs-Mac-mini-4:~ alexbrowne$ ipconfig getpacket en0 | awk -F "{|}" '/domain_name_server/ {print $2}'
192.168.7.1

Comment: Thanks for your kind offer to help...

Comment: I am aware that the work setup routed computers to the internal servers when the demoain I am trying to access. It looks as if this has been forced onto my Macs that had the work vpn installed. I am I right in saying that it loos like its pointing towards the router at home?